# Is there any sort of automated scripts for the answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Lot's of answers on Ask Ubuntu suggest to fix something manually e.g. via console etc. Is there any configuration management system available that can simply allow to write those scripts/recipes and execute them. Additionally, it would mean people can answer by simply posting a script/recipe that fixes everything.

Comment: `apturl` can be used to install packages directly with a button click in the browser, but it can't execute scripts. See its [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com//community/AptURL).

Comment: ehm isn't this intended for meta?

Comment: Executing scripts from a browser click?! Are you serious? `[click here](bash://'rm -Rf /*')`

Answer (score 5):

This is a terrible idea. There is obviously a huge security risk of lowering the barrier to accidentally running arbitrary code written by someone you don't know.